# Trouble while getting an array out of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

When I get an object, I want to get an array of objects that's on the object

```
const set = await SetsController.getSet(setID);

const setName = set.name;
const setId = set._id.toString();

console.log(setId);
console.log(set.cards);
```

`set` contains an array called `cards`.

When I do this:

```
console.log(set);
```

The whole `set` object prints, including the `cards` array.
However, when I do this:

```
console.log(set.cards);
```

it prints `undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(set);` and `console.log(typeof set);` look like?

Comment: What do you see in the `cards` property if you change `console.log(set)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(set))`?

Comment: @Kinglish ```console.log(typeof set);``` returns ```object```. ```console.log(set);``` returns ```{id: setId, cards: [new ObjectId(123), new ObjectId(456), ...], name: 'This Name', creationDate: '11/09/2020'}```

Comment: is this a MongoDB result set?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes it is

Comment: I added that into your question tags.

Comment: where does `cards` get populated?

Comment: @Joe After the promise of ```SetsController.getSet(setId);``` gets fullfilled

Comment: When I try that, it works as expected.  Can you create a minimal snippet that defines the schema, inserts a document, and then demonstrates the problem?